# RXJS v6 loads many unnecessary modules?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

I was [*told*](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3379#issuecomment-393567067) by Ben Lesh that  in rxjs6 ,  weh shouldn't do :

`import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';`

But

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Also for operators :

```
import {first, skipWhile}      from "rxjs/operators";
```

So I've changed my proj to v6 .

Here are the usages :

[image]

But look how many operators are in the bundle :

[image]

```
* Operator exports */
/** PURE_IMPORTS_START  PURE_IMPORTS_END */
export { audit } from '../internal/operators/audit';
export { auditTime } from '../internal/operators/auditTime';
export { buffer } from '../internal/operators/buffer';
export { bufferCount } from '../internal/operators/bufferCount';
...
...
```

[Full list is here](https://pastebin.com/ZqpfV6pX)

**Question:**

Why is that ? Am I importing the operators incorrectly ? And why do I see all those unused operators ?

[webpack file](https://gist.github.com/RoyiNamir/fbf49b7083d337425da932f1e45fd8f0)